# Cfdump equivalent in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, coldfusion, cfdump

I need help learning to debug ASP MVC 5 apps. I'd like to be able to spit out the values of variables at any time the way you can with `cfdump` in ColdFusion. Is this possible?

Comment: You would leverage Visual Studio's breakpoints to see what variables are within scope. This is much better than dumping values to the screen, because you have control over the values (search for immediate window). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at313d3f.aspx

Comment: Yes, I started out doing that, but some variables are only created at run time, such as when you navigate to a certain page, right? How would I use a breakpoint in that case?

Comment: Run your web application in debug mode and click through  each page until you hit your specified breakpoint.

Comment: Here is another tool for your consideration http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/profile-and-debug-your-aspnet-mvc-app-with-glimpse

Comment: You may use tracing feature in asp.net application.